# Power Series For a Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

$$
y'+\left(1+\frac{2}{x}\right)y=0
$$

I have been trying to solve it all night, but everytime I try to determine the values of the constants, everything equals to zero, I'm honestly at a loss here.

Everytime i tried this is what I'm getting to.

$$
2C_0x^{-1}+\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\left[\left(n+1\right)C_{n+1}+C_n+2C_{n+1}\right]=0
$$

Thanks in advance for all the feedback.

Comment: Forget the power series, solve it the normal way, then return to power series.

Comment: $(\ln y)' = -\left(1+\frac 2x\right)$